# Where to configure "ServerTokens" and "ServerSignature" for Apache2 on Ubuntu 11.10 server?

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Attempting to configure Apache2 on a new Ubuntu 11.10 web server. Changes to a recent version of Apache has shuffled some config variables around.

"ServerTokens" and "ServerSignature" were previously found in apache2.conf; not anymore.

I have read 2 differing views.

1. Manually add them to the end of the apache2.conf file, or
2. Are they being addressed in a different file

Can anyone confirm that #1 is right. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

All security related settings are in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/security`

Comment: on debian: /etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf